# Rails: How to multiple associations between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following association between Reviews and Users:

[image: Association]

Since I'm using Devise, I kept just a single Users table and identify the roles using client or seller columns (boolean).

So as you can imagine, I need to know the user that made the review and the user being "reviewed".

The first question is: **Can I make use of references while creating the migration? I manually created these columns like this: `t.integer :client_id, foreign_key: true` and `t.integer :seller_id, foreign_key: true`**

The second is: **How can I specify the relationship in the models? I did like this `has_many :reviews, foreign_key: "client_id"` and `has_many :reviews, foreign_key: "seller_id"` but i'm not sure if it's correct.**

Here's the full code of migration:

```rb
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
      t.text :description
      t.integer :rating, null: false
      t.integer :client_id, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :seller_id, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The User Model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :reviews, foreign_key: "client_id"
  has_many :reviews, foreign_key: "seller_id"
end
```

and the Review model:

```rb
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Rails Version: 6.0.3.2 - Ruby Version: 2.6.6**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you are trying to achieve.

First thing first, remove `foreign_key: true` in your `CreateReviews`  migration because it has no effect, you might want to index those two columns by replacing it with `index: true`.

Then in your `User` model have two different `has_many` associations eg

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :client_reviews, foreign_key: "client_id", class_name: 'Review'
  has_many :seller_reviews, foreign_key: "seller_id", class_name: 'Review'
end
```

Why two different associations? well because when you have two same associations it will always use the last association hence overriding the first one.

You might want to try it in your console and see the output, for your case if you inspect the query you will see that it is using `seller_id` column to find reviews if you try something like.

```rb
user = User.first
p user.reviews.to_sql
```

Now refactor your `Review` model to have something like this

```rb
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, foreign_key: :client_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :seller, foreign_key: :seller_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Now you can create `client_reviews` and `seller_reviews` and query each one

```rb
seller = User.create(name: 'Seller 1)
client = User.create(name: 'Client 1')

seller.seller_reviews.create(description: 'I like your product', client: client)

review = Review.first
p review.client
p review.seller
```

Hope it helps give the picture of what you can do.